# Connecting a form with PayPal pay-button to MySQL database?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, paypal

I am wondering how to connect my form with a PayPal's pay button to a MySQL database?

I have a form with `username` and `e-mail` address which my customers must fill in and then click a PayPal's pay button. After they fill in the information and click the pay-button, they will be directed to PayPal's payment site. What I want to happen is that when the payment is completed, the information they filled in gets stored on my database.

I hope it was understandable. Does anyone know how I should proceed? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. This post is too broad, you should at least post what you have tried so far to get an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/) for this.  [This template](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-ipn-template) will get your data saved in MySQL very quickly and easily.

All you gotta do is edit the config file with your db credentials and then run the installer to create all of the tables/fields.

Then set up IPN in your PayPal account to point to the ipn-listener.php file that comes with the template.  From that point on, any transaction that hits your PayPal account will end up saved in your database.